# How can I prevent my button from being mangled?

Tags: html, css

I have a css styled button that is being completely mangled and showing strangely on multiple lines. However if the button is set as a input instead of a link the button looks perfect.  How can I get my link button to look the same as the input button?

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tasenudr/

html:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <table style="width:80%;">
        <tr>
            <td style=" text-align: left;   vertical-align: middle;">
                <BR>    <a class="btn" target="_parent" href="index.php?ts=fq">Daily&#x00A;Starting from:&#x00A;$15.22</a>

            </td>
            <td style=" width: 4%; text-align: left;    vertical-align: middle; text-align:right;">
                <BR>
                <input type="submit" value="6 Month Plans Starting from: $75.36" style="width:90px; top:50px; height:115px; white-space: normal;" class="btn">
                </submit>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {

    background: #FFCC02;

    border: none;

    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;

    color: #585858;

    border-radius: 4px;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;

    font-weight: bold;

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

}

.btn:hover {

    color: #333;

    background-color: #EBEBEB;

}
```

The button on the left is mangled, but the button on the right looks perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button is an inline element.

Give it a `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to your `.btn` css rule to prevent the `inline` native display of the element from mangling the text inside of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/tasenudr/1/

```
.btn {

    background: #FFCC02;

    display: block;

    border: none;

    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;

    color: #585858;

    border-radius: 4px;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;

    font-weight: bold;

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `.btn` to `display: inline-block` OR `display: block` for this to work properly.

**Updated fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/tasenudr/3/

```
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```